# SQL 2 Inner Joins on the same field

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have 3 tables as seen from the image below. I have been able to join the `projects.project_id` to the `sprints.project_id` and the `projects.manager_id` to the `users.user_id` however, also want to join the `users.user_id` to the `projects.product_owner_id` I had tried to

```
INNER JOIN users ON projects.manager_id = users.user_id 
AND projects.product_owner_id = users.user_id
```

Although this returned now results. I want in my list view to be able to list the Manager ID and Products Owner ID in a ListView Control.

[image]

Below is my current SQL Query any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT        
    projects.project_name, projects.manager_id, 
    projects.product_owner_id, projects.project_description, 
    projects.status, 
    sprints.sprint_name, sprints.sprint_start_date, 
    sprints.sprint_length, sprints.work_mon, 
    sprints.work_tue, sprints.work_wed, sprints.work_thu, 
    sprints.work_fri, sprints.work_sat, sprints.work_sun, 
    projects.project_id, sprints.project_id AS Expr1, 
    sprints.sprint_id, users.username
FROM
    projects 
INNER JOIN
    users ON projects.manager_id = users.user_id 
INNER JOIN
    sprints ON projects.project_id = sprints.project_id
WHERE        
    (projects.project_id = @project_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace inner join with left outer join (since there are products without owner filled) and make a separate join the two associations - manager and owner:

```
...
INNER JOIN users manager ON projects.manager_id = manager.user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users owner ON projects.product_owner_id = owner.user_id 
...
```

Comment: That is great, thank you. I'm not sure if you can help with a further issue. The results still only output one username, the username for the `manager_id`. How can I make it so there is a separate username for both the manager and product owner?

Comment: `select projects.project_name, owner.username as OwnerName, manager.username as ManagerName, ...` the thing is once a table is used in a join and has an alias, it's columns can be referenced in the select clause by this alias.